# In visual studio code - what is the name of the ins key on the num pad (keybindings.json)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to assign the ins key on the numpad to paste.

I have tried

```
{ "key": "numpad_ins",                "command": "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" }
```

Comment: This question lack a lot of information, This code does not tells us anythings, you should consider reading the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to create a well construct and answerable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the numpad is activated, it's `numpad0`, and when it's not: `insert`.

You can test your bindings in the `keybindings.json` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on Windows and Linux or with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on macOS, two times in a row. A little popup window will appear and you can then press various keys to test for their names.

[image]